# If a question is changed making an answer invalid, how should the community respond?

Tags: discussion, bug

**If a question is changed making an answer invalid, how should the community respond?**

I refer to (among other places) a question [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/137802/need-a-specific-event-that-wrecks-the-surface-allows-the-race-to-survive-in-bun), and to an answer [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/137802/need-a-specific-event-that-wrecks-the-surface-allows-the-race-to-survive-in-bun/137807#137807).

The answer surely becomes invalid as soon as the question is changed, without the original answerer's consent deletion would be high handed, yet an answer, that is nonsensicle in regards of the current version of the question - this is upvoted above answers which answer the question as presently asserted.

> we always recommend that edits shall not invalidate existing answers,
>   as it is at least a lack of respect toward the effort put by the
>   answerer in writing the answer.

Well, to me that sounds like a respectable attitude, that being said it's the first I've heard of it.

> Of course this is often little understood and neglected, especially by
>   new users, and then it's up to the community to be alert.

Well, I'm a part of the community, I came to alert on seeing this (not for the first time) and apparently in some (unspecified way) it's up to me. Damed if I know what to do about it.

> A possible and not preferred workaround is that the poster of the
>   answer edits it adding a note that the answer refers to a previous
>   version of the question.

<sub>*[L.Dutch.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/if-a-question-is-changed-making-an-answer-invalid-how-should-the-community-resp)*</sub>

Hmm, "previous version of the question" - that would be something that the majority of members (57,000+ Versus 500 or so) **could not view**, ie. an *edit history*. Should we be making cryptic comments about invisible text? I think not. (Invisible to the majority that is.)

Of course, if the answer by L.Dutch is modified to answer this question as-is, then that invalidates the question's quotes from his answer, making the universe swallow itself.

This whole thing could become a self circling mess decending into hell unless clear rules are specified *and enforced*.

I say again:

**If a question is changed making an answer invalid, how should the community respond?**

<sub>*It was not my intention to offend L.Dutch in any way, it was not my intention to use any answer to the first version of my question as a straw man. That was entirely opportunistic. I may change the question again without further warning or justification. Or not.*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand what you are asking. Anyway, we always recommend that edits shall not invalidate existing answers, as it is at least a lack of respect toward the effort put by the answerer in writing the answer.

Of course this is often little understood and neglected, especially by new users, and then it's up to the community to be alert.

A possible and not preferred workaround is that the poster of the answer edits it adding a note that the answer refers to a previous version of the question.

Comment: You answered just fine, I could have phrased it better by asking, "what is the position on..." - but this would not have caused anything to be resolved, I ask for resolution. What I personally need to do is ask in a better way, in order to provoke constructive change. So, that's what I'll do here. Sorry if it invalidates your answer in the process.